# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', Reason Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x608000256260> was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I've joined in a company last week, I got an already developed project which is developped in 2012, 13, 14, 2015 and i need to reopen it again now after 1.5 years. I don't understand the problem, But I guess the proplem is because of Coredata.

After logged when fetching data to display on home view table

In the following code i faced crash in the last line.

Can some one please help me

**In AppDelegate:**

```
- (NSArray*)getManagedObjectsArrayForEntity:(NSString*)entityName 
                               sortByFields:(NSArray*)sortByFields 
                                  predicate:(NSPredicate*)predicate
                                  ascending:(BOOL)ascending {



    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:-1];

    // Set the sort descriptor
    if (sortByFields) {
        NSMutableArray *sortDescriptors = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSString *sortByField in sortByFields) {
            NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortByField ascending:ascending];
            [sortDescriptors addObject:sortDescriptor];
            [sortDescriptor release];
        }
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    }

    if (predicate) {
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        //DDLogVerbose(@"Predicate: %@", [predicate description]);
    }


    NSError *error;
    //=== ***

    return [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]; //<=== Crash here in this lines

}
```

Comment: add exception breakpoint and check that actually where your code is broken .

Comment: Does the entity you're fetching have NSOrderedSet property?

Comment: @user1963877 Yes it has order NSOrderedSet property sir

Comment: @KKRocks, yes I've checked with exceptional breakpoint code is broken at last line at resturn

Comment: Try regenerating entity with normal NSSet and see if it still causes a crash. Also, on which iOS versions does this happen?

Comment: @user1963877 on ios 10.2 it happening